# How to denote a set of functions

Tags: functions

Say there is an unknown function $h(x)$ $$\int_A^B h(x) = c$$ $A$, $B$ and $c$ are known. So $h(x)$ can have various forms on the range $[A,B]$. I want to know how to denote the set of functions for $h(x)$. I know the notation for a set is $\{...\}$.

So would it be: $\{h(x)|\int_A^B h(x) = c\}$? Or is there a different way to refer to a bunch of different possible functions?

I intend to narrow down this set by gradually introducing boundary restrictions/conditions. E.g. $h(x) \in \mathbb R$ and $h(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)$ with $g(x)$ known.

Comment: Use $\{h:[A,B]\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}\vert\int_A^B h(x)dx = 3\}$. $h(x)$ is the *value* of $h$ in $x$.

Comment: The way you're writing the set is accurate. You might want to say $h\in C^0([A,B])$ (if your functions are continuous) or something similar, just to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments: try

- $\{h \in C([A,B])\vert\int_A^B h(x)\,dx = c\}$ or
- $\{h \in L^1([A,B])\vert\int_A^B h(x)dx = c\}$

depending on what kind of functions you consider. Simply saying *functions with integral equal to $3$* is usually ambiguous: there are different kinds of integrals.

Avoid writing $h(x)$ when you mean $h$.

Comment: Is first variant posible to denote a set of continuous piecewise linear function?